# Attributing multiple Peer objects to a single item in legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

### Simplified Problem

I'm plotting 10 items.

To generate my plot I am creating 10 independent `Line` objects  in a for loop

```
x=1:10;y=1;10;names = num2str((1:10)');
for i = 1:10
    my_plots(i) = plot(x(i),y(i),'.','Color',rgb(i,:),'MarkerSize',14); 
end
legend(my_plots,names);
```

[image: Simple]

When I click on an item in the legend it toggles visibility of the corresponding line

(`legHandle.ItemHitFcn = toggleLegendItem`).

```
function toggleLegendItem(src,evnt)

    if strcmp(evnt.Peer.Visible,'on')
        evnt.Peer.Visible = 'off';
    else 
       evnt.Peer.Visible= 'on';
    end

end
```

**This works fine**

---

I run into issues when some of my plots are actually the same category.
[image: Complex]

In this simple example, I could combine lines 1:5 into one object in a number of different ways, and pass the combined object to the legend as a single item in `my_plots`.

### Actual problem

All of my `line` objects are distributed between several independent axes/subplots. Each `axis` has to remain independent because I need to be able to freely rotate each subplot without disturbing the other plots.

### Progress so far

I've been able to build a shared legend between axes (because same class items share the same color, I only need to link the first `line` for each class), but I cannot figure out how to link multiple `line` objects to a single legend item, so that I am able to properly all `lines` across `axes` on each legend item callback.

I have an array of lines.

```
  {{Line Line Line}}
  {{Line Line Line}} 
  {{Line Line Line}}
  ...
  {{Line Line Line}}
```

**Basically what I need to do is set multiple `Peer` objects to a single legend item, but I am not sure if that is possible.**

If someone has another solution that allows for combing multiple `line` handles across axes that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at the `legend()` function, I found that it's not possible to instantiate a legend with multiple `Peer` objects per item. There may be a way to go back and add multiple references via some sort of "combined object" but I'm not sure if a "combined object" exists that can handle objects with different `Parent` handles.

A quick fix to my problem (which was attributing a callback to the same item in multiple axes) was to use the shared properties within each class and across axes to get the handles for all items within each class. In this case I already assigned color to be distinctive between categories but a more objective property like `Tag` could also be used.

```
function toggleLegendItem(src,evnt)
    % Find all items in this category
    obj = findobj(findall(gcf,'type','Scatter'),'CData',evnt.Peer.CData);

    for oid = 1:length(obj) 
        if strcmp(obj(oid).Visible,'on')
            obj(oid).Visible = 'off';
        else 
           obj(oid).Visible= 'on';
        end
    end
end
```

The one nuisance that this solution leaves is that the legend is a `child` of only one axis. If each category is not present in all axes, then the color for those missing categories may not show up. Luckily when you toggle each item's visibility   the color appears and functions as normal. I would guess some other errors like this could occur.